# UISlider with 2 sounds on both 0 value and 1 value

Tags: xcode, swift

I was wondering if someone could explain to me how to setup the following. I have always been working with sliders just as volume adjustment, but I know like to use it in a different way. I'd like to have one sound that will sound when I move the slider all the way to the left and a sound the will sound when the slider is all the way to the left, eventually I would like to have a sound that sounds when the slider is in the middle. The idea is not that the sounds fade in or out. The sound will only be hearable when the slider is on the correct spot all the way to the left, right or middle. Any ideas on how to approach this in Xcode writing in swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    if (sender.value == 0) {
        // play sound 0
    }
    else if (sender.value == 0.5) {
        // play sound 0.5
    }
    else if (sender.value == 1.0) {
        // play sound 1.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Last question wasn't in Swift like you asked for, here's how I would do it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBAction func sliderChanged(sender: UISlider) {
      if sender.value == 0 {
        //play your sound for 0
      }
      else if sender.value == 0.5 {
        //play your sound for 1/2
      }
      else if sender.value == 1 {
        //play your sound for 1
      }
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      //Your setup here
   }

}
```

If you're having troubles, remember to check the Interface Builder and change the max value of the slider to 1.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel ! I appreciate the help ! I did come up with a similar solution just know, this confirms it. Thanks !